# alert once in Javascript

Tags: javascript, alert, onchange

I have two text input fields in an HTML form, and I would like to use JavaScript for the needed validation. If there is input in the second text field while the first text input field is empty or left blank, my JavaScript should alert "Please enter text1 first."

However, the alert box always pops out more than once and users may find it annoying. First, when I type something in **text2**. Second, when I click on **text1** to input something. Is there a way for the alert box to display only once, possibly only on the first scenario?

```
<script>
$("#text2").on("change",function(){ 
var t1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
if (t1 == "")
alert("Please enter text1 first.");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Users will find any alert annoying...

Comment: This isn't syntactically valid JavaScript.

Comment: use a boolean such as isShow.

Or just simply append a warning under the input field and remove it after the input is validated , less annoying

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.one()` function, instead of `.on()`

```
<script>
    $("#text2").one("change", function (event) { 
        var t1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;

        if (t1 === "") {
            alert("Please enter text1 first.");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a UX answer here, but...

Users will find *any* number of alerts annoying (except zero).

When multiple inputs are presented, it's assumed they can be filled out in any order. Most people will go first-to-last, but sometimes it may be more convenient to fill them out more freestyle.

If you don't want to allow users to type anything in the second one until they've completed the first one, then *don't show it yet*. Show only the first input, get the user's input, then show the second one.

And finally, make good use of `<input ... required />` if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is Really Bad User Experience™. You shouldn't be doing this for several reasons:

1. Showing alerts for common misuses of your interface is annoying
2. This does not prevent the user to fill the input
3. Your solution does not guide the user to the correct (intended) use of your interface

Let me suggest something slightly better:

#### Disabling and enabling one input depending on the emptiness of another input

```
<script>
$('input#text1').change(function() {
  var $i2 = $('input#text2');

  if($(this).val().length() == 0) {
    $i2.attr('disabled','disabled');
    $i2.val('');
  } else {
    $i2.removeAttr('disable');
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#text2").change(function() {
if ($("#text1").val() === ""){
  alert("Please enter text1 first.");
}  });
```